# SQL Microsoft Access Show immediate next row

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to show rowa and rowb (right below it) if rowa is true in the WHERE statement. I do have it ORDER BY Date, but that wouldn't affect anything.  Are there any quick ways of showing the rowb if rowa is shown?

My code is...

```
SELECT Roster.`Complete Name`, RS1018to1024.`Day of Week`, RS1018to1024.`Date`, RS1018to1024.`Time Type`, RS1018to1024.`Attribute`, RS1018to1024.`Value`, RS1018to1024.`Hourly value (in decimals)`

FROM Roster 

INNER JOIN RS1018to1024 ON Roster.GIN = RS1018to1024.GIN
WHERE (RS1018to1024.`Hourly value (in decimals)` >15 AND RS1018to1024.`Time Type`='Wellsite/Job/Vessel' OR RS1018to1024.Attribute='Job ID'  ) 
OR (RS1018to1024.`Time Type`='On Office-Base-Lab' AND RS1018to1024.Attribute='Regular Work Day' AND RS1018to1024.`Hourly value (in decimals)`>8)  

ORDER BY RS1018to1024.`Complete Name`, RS1018to1024.`Date`, RS1018to1024.`Attribute` DESC;

Day of Week|   Date    | Time Type |  Attribute    | Value     | Hourly value

Tues       |20-Oct-2015| Wellsite  |  Reg Work Day | RGWD      | 16.8

Tues       |20-Oct-2015| Wellsite  |  Job ID       | 2213      |

Friday     |23-Oct-2015| Wellsite  |  Job ID       | 2251      |

Wed        |21-Oct-2015| Wellsite  |  Reg Work Day | RGWD      | 24

Tues       |21-Oct-2015| Wellsite  |  Job ID       | 2317      |

Sunday     |18-Oct-2015| On Office |  Reg Work Day | RGWD      | 12.2

CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Day_of_Week                VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Date                       VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL
  ,Time_Type                  VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL
  ,Attribute                  VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
  ,Value                      VARCHAR(28) NOT NULL
  ,Hourly_value_in_decimals   NUMERIC(5,2)
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('Tuesday','20-Oct-15','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Regular Work Day','RGWD - Regular Work Day (BR)',16.75);
INSERT INTO mytable(Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('Tuesday','20-Oct-15','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Job ID','2213840',NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('Friday','23-Oct-15','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Job ID','2212599',NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('Friday','23-Oct-15','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Regular Work Day','RGWD - Regular Work Day (BR)',23.87);
INSERT INTO mytable(Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('Saturday','24-Oct-15','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Job ID','2212599',NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('Sunday','18-Oct-15','On Office-Base-Lab','Regular Work Day','RGWD - Regular Work Day (BR)',19.87);
INSERT INTO mytable(Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('Monday','19-Oct-15','On Office-Base-Lab','Regular Work Day','RGWD - Regular Work Day (BR)',11.17);
```

What I would want to see is...

```
Day of Week|   Date    | Time Type |  Attribute    | Value     | Hourly value

Tues       |20-Oct-2015| Wellsite  |  Reg Work Day | RGWD      | 16.8

Tues       |20-Oct-2015| Wellsite  |  Job ID       | 2213      |

Wed        |21-Oct-2015| Wellsite  |  Reg Work Day | RGWD      | 24

Tues       |21-Oct-2015| Wellsite  |  Job ID       | 2317      |

Sunday     |18-Oct-2015| On Office |  Reg Work Day | RGWD      | 12.2

CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Day_of_Week                VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Date                       VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL
  ,Time_Type                  VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL
  ,Attribute                  VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
  ,Value                      VARCHAR(28) NOT NULL
  ,Hourly_value_in_decimals   NUMERIC(5,2)
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('Tuesday','20-Oct-15','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Regular Work Day','RGWD - Regular Work Day (BR)',16.75);
INSERT INTO mytable(Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('Tuesday','20-Oct-15','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Job ID','2213840',NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('Friday','23-Oct-15','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Regular Work Day','RGWD - Regular Work Day (BR)',23.87);
INSERT INTO mytable(Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('Saturday','24-Oct-15','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Job ID','2212599',NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('Sunday','18-Oct-15','On Office-Base-Lab','Regular Work Day','RGWD - Regular Work Day (BR)',19.87);
INSERT INTO mytable(Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('Monday','19-Oct-15','On Office-Base-Lab','Regular Work Day','RGWD - Regular Work Day (BR)',11.17);
```

So, every Time Type that says Wellsite needs two rows. One for the Reg Work Day and the next row showing the Job ID.  My code is showing all rows that have Job ID which is what I need to get rid of unless they have the Reg Work Day above it.  Also, I have a row of On Office Time Type that is fine and I'm not having any issues with.

Comment: `select row, row, row from boat`  http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Can you please share your table's structure, some sample data and the result you're trying to get? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your requirements is you assume that the data is ordered and you this row and the next row.  However in SQL data is not ordered you need a column to use on an ORDER BY clause to get an order.

Looking at your example data it seems that the two rows you want both have the same date.  IF THIS IS THE CASE then the solution is not hard.  You do it like this:

First you get a list of dates that meet the criteria.

```
SELECT `Date` 
FROM ROSTER 
WHERE `Hourly Value` > 15 AND Attribute = 'Reg Work Day'
```

Then you take this list as the criteria for selecting the rest of the table

```
SELECT *
FROM ROSTER
WHERE `Date` IN (
  SELECT `Date` 
  FROM ROSTER 
  WHERE `Hourly Value` > 15 AND Attribute = 'Reg Work Day'
) sub
```

The takeaway here is that you can't think ordered and sequential in SQL -- you have to think in set -- SQL deals in sets.

Comment: I'm needing something more complex than this.  I'm more of looking to try to pair up consecutive rows. For example, if row(m) is >15 than show row(m) and row(n).  If row(m) is not >15 than don't show row(m) or row(n).

Comment: The problem with your question is you assume tables are ordered.  In SQL tables are not ordered -- you add the order in with an ORDER BY statement so how do I know what the "next'' row is?

Comment: That does help a lot. Thank you! Is there a way to specify to look at that for a list of employees? So, if my table above were the rows for one employee, but I had another group for other employees.  Where some did not work >15. Right now if one person worked more than 15 hours on the 18th than all rows with the 18th are shown.  I have a column for Names (lastname,firstname) or IDNumbers.

Comment: @user3827129 - you should upvote my answer and select it as answering your question if it did so.  It sounds like you are asking another question.  I believe I know the answer but you should ask another question as another question not put another question in the comments.

Comment: I would upvote your answer, but I need 15 reputations and I only have 5. Is there some way I can work around or get 10 more reputations to get you your upvote?

Comment: @user3827129 -- just ask another question and follow the FAQ on asking a good question -- if you ask a good one you will get upvotes.  15 comes quick.