# pull pairs from table with multiple requirements

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have a database of multiple employees and how many hours they work.  Please see below.
So, every Time.Type that says Wellsite needs two rows. One for the Attribute: Reg Work Day and the next row showing the Attribute: Job ID. My code is showing all rows that have Job ID which is what I need to get rid of unless they have the Reg Work Day above it that meets my condition (see below). Also, I have a row of On Office Time Type that is fine and I'm not having any issues with.

I've been assisted to do this, but for one employee.  Now I need my data to work through this process for multiple employees.

The condition I need to be true is when a row has a Time.Type of "Wellsite/Job/Vessel" and an Attribute that says "Regular Work Day" the "Hourly Value" needs to be >15.  Also, I need the row right below it which has an Attribute of "Job ID" with a job number under the "value" tab too.  From what I have learned is that the Date column can be used to keep the rows together, but i just need it to work for the certain employees/days rather than everything.

The table below shows what I have and what I want it to do is below this table..

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Complete_Name              VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Day_of_Week                VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
  ,Date                       VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
  ,Time_Type                  VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL
  ,Attribute                  VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
  ,Value                      VARCHAR(28) NOT NULL
  ,Hourly_value_in_decimals   NUMERIC(5,2)
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Complete_Name,Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('EmployeeA','Tuesday','20-Oct-2015','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Regular Work Day','RGWD - Regular Work Day (BR)',16.75);
INSERT INTO mytable(Complete_Name,Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('EmployeeA','Tuesday','20-Oct-2015','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Job ID','2213840',NULL);
INSERT INTO mytable(Complete_Name,Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('EmployeeB','Tuesday','20-Oct-15','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Regular Work Day','RGWD - Regular Work Day (BR)',2.25);
INSERT INTO mytable(Complete_Name,Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('EmployeeB','Tuesday','20-Oct-15','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Job ID','2213840',NULL);
```

Table:

```
Complete_Name Day_of_Week Date        Time_Type           Attribute        Value                        Hourly_value_in_decimals
------------- ----------- ----------- ------------------- ---------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------------------
EmployeeA     Tuesday     20-Oct-2015 Wellsite/Job/Vessel Regular Work Day RGWD - Regular Work Day (BR) 16.75
EmployeeA     Tuesday     20-Oct-2015 Wellsite/Job/Vessel Job ID           2213840                      NULL
EmployeeB     Tuesday     20-Oct-15   Wellsite/Job/Vessel Regular Work Day RGWD - Regular Work Day (BR) 2.25
EmployeeB     Tuesday     20-Oct-15   Wellsite/Job/Vessel Job ID           2213840                      NULL
```

What I want to see is...

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Complete_Name              VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Day_of_Week                VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
  ,Date                       VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
  ,Time_Type                  VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL
  ,Attribute                  VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL
  ,Value                      VARCHAR(28) NOT NULL
  ,Hourly_value_in_decimals   NUMERIC(5,2)
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Complete_Name,Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('EmployeeA','Tuesday','20-Oct-2015','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Regular Work Day','RGWD - Regular Work Day (BR)',16.75);
INSERT INTO mytable(Complete_Name,Day_of_Week,Date,Time_Type,Attribute,Value,Hourly_value_in_decimals) VALUES ('EmployeeA','Tuesday','20-Oct-2015','Wellsite/Job/Vessel','Job ID','2213840',NULL);
```

Table:

```
Complete_Name Day_of_Week Date        Time_Type           Attribute        Value                        Hourly_value_in_decimals
------------- ----------- ----------- ------------------- ---------------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------------------
EmployeeA     Tuesday     20-Oct-2015 Wellsite/Job/Vessel Regular Work Day RGWD - Regular Work Day (BR) 16.75
EmployeeA     Tuesday     20-Oct-2015 Wellsite/Job/Vessel Job ID           2213840                      NULL
```

Comment: Do *not* store everything as `VARCHAR`... Store values as their appropriate data type.  Even in your sample data, you have dates being stored as strings with differing formats...

Comment: prior question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440088/sql-microsoft-access-show-immediate-next-row/33440572#33440572

Comment: I need to read this again to understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So building on my prior answer you need to pull for different employees based on different criteria.

For example employee name Hogan might want days > 15 while employee named NotHogan might want days > 24.

To do this you put the criteria in a table (in the example below I build the table dynamically) and then join to that table to get the dates and names required.

Then I join to this result to get the final data.

```
SELECT *
FROM ROSTER
JOIN (
  -- A list of dates and users we want to select
  SELECT `Date`, Name 
  FROM ROSTER 
  JOIN (
      -- Innermost table, our criteria, this can be an actual table in your db
      SELECT 'Hogan' as N, 15 as C 
         UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'NotHogan' as N, 24 as C 
  ) Criteria ON
      Criteria.N = ROSTER.Name AND 
      ROSTER.`Hourly Value` > Criteria.C AND  
      Attribute = 'Reg Work Day'
) sub ON ROSTER.`Date` = sub.`Date` and ROSTER.Name = Sub.Name
```